# trying to draw a sprite onto canvas but I am missing something

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```js
window.onload = function(){
  theVideo();
  playVideo();
  Move();
  Draw();
};
let objectInfo = {
    canvas: null,
    context: null,
    // Number of sprites
    numberOfFrames: 16,        
    image: null,
    imageWidth: 128,
    imageHeight: 192,
    frameIndex: 0,
    frameWidth: 0,
    // Animation interval (ms)
    msInterval: 1000,        
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
};
const imageFile = "shaggy.png";
 function Draw(){
  objectInfo.context.drawImage(myImage, shift, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, 120, 25, frameWidth, frameHeight);
 }
//image setup
window.onload= function () {

    // Canvas setup
    objectInfo.canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
    objectInfo.context = objectInfo.canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Image setup
    objectInfo.image = new Image();
    objectInfo.image.onload = function() {

        // The this object refers to image because within image onload event handler
        objectInfo.imageWidth = this.width;
        objectInfo.imageHeight = this.height;

        // Calculate framewidth (size of each sprite)
        objectInfo.frameWidth = objectInfo.imageWidth / objectInfo.numberOfFrames;
    };
    // Load image
    objectInfo.image.src = imageFile;

};

var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;

//move image
function Move(e){
  //right
  if(e.keyCode==39){
      xPos+=5;
  }
  //left
  if(e.keyCode==37){
      xPos-=5;
  }
  //up
   if(e.keyCode==38){
      yPos-=5;
   }
   //down
    if(e.keyCode==40){
      yPos+=5;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sprite</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Peyton">
    <meta name="description" content="115">
    <link rel= 'stylesheet' href="p4.css">
    <script src="p4.js"> </script>
      <style>canvas { border: 1px solid black; }</style>  
<body>
    <canvas width= "1300" height= "600" id= "myCanvas">

    <video id="video" controls >       
        <source src="ScoobyDooV.mp4"/>
        <source src="ScoobyDooV.ogv"/>
    </video>

    </canvas>
    </body>
  
    </html>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <main id="#wrapper"><br>
    
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm really new to coding and am not sure what I am missing to call my sprite and draw the first image onto the canvas. I later have to call each measurement of my sprite and assign to a function keydown event to make it look like its walking each direction so if I could get any guidance on that too that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling Draw before the image is loaded. Try placing the `Draw()` call within the image.onload method.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `window.onload` twice, only one out of your two callbacks will be executed

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely not suited to the task you are attempting. Animations require regular rendering. There is a huge amount of missing code in your example so i can really solve any problems directly.

So just thought I would give an example of how to load, animate, and render sprites sheets.

## Sprite sheets

There are many ways to handle sprite sheets, though I find that using a standard method for all sprite sheets makes life easy.

Some sprite sheets have a regular layout and evenly spaced sprites, other sprite sheets, have been packed together to conserve pixels and memory.

Each sprite has a location on the sheet, the top left corner and the size as width and height.

You can attach an array of these locations to an image

For example the next function creates sprites for a regular layout (like image in your question)

```
function createSprites(width, height, columns, rows, image) {
  const sprites = [];
  var w = width / columns;
  var h = height / rows;
  var ix, iy;
  for (iy = 0; iy < rows; iy++) {
    for (ix = 0; ix < columns; ix++) {
      const x = ix * w;
      const y = iy * h;
      sprites.push({ x, y, w, h });
    }
  }
  image.sprites = sprites;
}
```

The array is added to the img so you don't have to add additional management

You can then draw the sprite by creating a custom draw function.

```
function drawSprite(img, sprIndex, x, y) {
  const spr = img.sprites[sprIndex];
  ctx.drawImage(img,
    spr.x, spr.y, spr.w, spr.h, // location on sprite sheet
    x , y  ,       // location on canvas
    spr.w, spr.h, // size on canvas;
  );

}
```

You pass the sprite sheet image, the sprite index in the sprite array, and the location you want to draw the sprite.

Easy as

Because you likely know the size of the sprite sheet, and the location of the sprites you don't have to wait for the image to load to attach the sprite data.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const spriteSheet = new Image;
spriteSheet.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOrC1.png";
// The image size is known so you dont have to wait for it to load
createSprites(128, 192, 4, 4, spriteSheet); // add a array of sprite locations


// It is important that the sprite sizes are integers
// width must be divisible by columns and height by rows
function createSprites(width, height, columns, rows, image) {
  const sprites = [];
  var w = width / columns;
  var h = height / rows;
  var ix, iy;
  for (iy = 0; iy < rows; iy++) {
    for (ix = 0; ix < columns; ix++) {
      const x = ix * w;
      const y = iy * h;
      sprites.push({ x, y, w, h });
    }
  }
  image.sprites = sprites;
}


function drawSprite(img, sprIndex, x, y) {
  const spr = img.sprites[sprIndex];
  ctx.drawImage(img,
    spr.x, spr.y, spr.w, spr.h, // location on sprite sheet
    x , y , // location on canvas
    spr.w, spr.h, // size on canvas;
  );

}

const walkerInfo = {
  framesPerDir: 4,
  movements: [{x: 0,y: 3 },{ x: -5, y: 0 }, { x: 5, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: -3 } ],
}
const walker = {
  dir: 0, // 0,1,2,3 
  time: 0, // time in Frames 
  rate: 0, // steps per frame
  x: 0, // position
  y: 0, // 
  update() {
    this.time += 1;
    // only move when sprite frame changes
    if ((this.time % this.rate) === 0) {
      this.x += walkerInfo.movements[this.dir].x;
      this.y += walkerInfo.movements[this.dir].y;
      if(this.x < -128 || this.x > canvas.width ||
         this.y < -192 || this.y > canvas.height) {
         this.x = randI(canvas.width);
         this.y = randI(canvas.height);
         this.dir = randI(4)
         this.rate = randI(6, 12)         
         
      }
    }
    if(randI(1000) === 0){
          this.dir = (this.dir + (randI(2) ? 2 : 1)) % 4;
          this.rate = randI(6, 12)   
    }

    
  },
  draw() {
    var index = this.dir * walkerInfo.framesPerDir;
    index += (this.time / this.rate | 0) % walkerInfo.framesPerDir;
    drawSprite(
      spriteSheet, index,
      this.x, this.y
    );
  }

}

function createWalker(x = randI(w), y = randI(h), dir = randI(4), rate = randI(6, 18)) {
  return { ...walker, x, y, dir, rate, time: randI(100) };
}
const walkers = [];


// main update function
function update(timer) {
  globalTime = timer;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
  if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight) {
    cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
    ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
  } else {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  }
  
  
  if (spriteSheet.complete) { // has the image loaded
    if (randI(walkers.length) === 0) { // odd 1/100 to create a walker
      walkers.push(createWalker());
    }
    walkers.sort((a,b)=>a.y - b.y);
    eachOf(walkers, walk => walk.update());
    eachOf(walkers, walk => walk.draw());

  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);



















var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2; // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var globalTime;


const randI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0;
const rand = (min = 1, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const eachOf = (array, cb) => {
  var i = 0;
  const len = array.length;
  while (i < len && cb(array[i], i++, len) !== true);
};
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```